# reducing code repetition using Math object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've this code:

```
if(data > 100) {
    if(data <= 1000) {
        otherValue = 10;
    } else if (data > 1000 && data <=2000) {
        otherValue = 20;
    } else if (data > 2000 && data <=3000) {
        otherValue = 30;
    }
     ......
     ......
}
```

I can't keep doing this up till, let's say, 20k. That would be terrible. And I can't seem to figure out an optimal code solution for it either.

Comment: is the condition connected to the value to assign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't clearly defined your requirement, but it seems like this should work.

```js
var data = 14281;
var otherValue;

if(data > 100) {
    otherValue = 10 * Math.ceil(data / 1000);
}

console.log(otherValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you never need to repeat a test that you've already ruled out by previous tests. In your code, this is all the `>` tests in the `else if` statements, which you can remove:

```
if(data > 100) {
    if(data <= 1000) {
        otherValue = 10;
    } else if ( /* data > 1000 && */ data <=2000) {
        otherValue = 20;
    } else if ( /* data > 2000 && */ data <=3000) {
        otherValue = 30;
    }
     ......
     ......
}
```

Next, what do you set `otherValue` to when `data <= 100`? I don't see any code to handle that case.

Finally, disregarding the `data <= 100` case, if the pattern of `if` statements continues every 1000 as in the example, you can use `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()` to calculate `otherValue` as shown in [JLRishe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242887/1202830). Just be sure to handle separately any cases that don't fit that pattern such as `data <= 100`.

Comment: thank you very much sir, for you've explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions could be designed in simpler way:

```
if(data <= 1000) {
    ...
} else if (data > 1000 /*Here data have to be > 1000, bacause of else branch.*/&& ... ) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to make it more simpler, what about like this?

```
if (data > 100 && data <= 20000) {
    otherValue = Math.ceil(data/1000)*10;
}
```